# Efficiently filtering a dictionary in-place

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

We have a dictionary `d1` and a condition `cond`. We want d1 to contain only the values  that satisfy the condition `cond`. One way to do it is:

```
d1 = {k:v for k,v in d1.items() if cond(v)}
```

But, this creates a new dictionary, which may be very memory-inefficient if `d1` is large.

Another option is:

```
for k,v in d1.items():
    if not cond(v):
       d1.pop(k)
```

But, this modifies the dictionary while it is iterated upon, and generates an error: "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration".

What is the correct way in Python 3 to filter a dictionary in-place?

Comment: Why do you think the first way is inefficient? `d1.items()` in py 3 creates only a view, it does not copy the dict

Comment: @Chris_Rands but, doesn't the command "{k:v for k,v in d1.items() if cond(v)}" create a new dictionary, that is then placed into the variable "d1"?

Comment: I see, so you want to maximise memory efficiency? i'll vote to re-open the dupe is about speed

Comment: Is the set of keys that satisfy `cond(v)` likely to be large? Also, how large are you expecting `d1` to become?

Comment: @JoelCornett I expect the set of passing keys to have several tens of thousands of string keys. I am not sure how much memory does this require in Python.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi ok, keep in mind that when you copy a dict, you’re only duplicating the data structure, not the strings that are stored in the data structure, those items are merely stored as references.

Comment: Depending on your memory constraints, it may be perfectly acceptable to duplicate the structure. If memory usage is an issue, you might consider creating wrapper “view” classes that behave like a dict, but lazily invoke `cond` when a key is looked up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are not many keys the corresponding values of which satisfy the condition, then you might first aggregate the keys and then prune the dictionary:

```
for k in [k for k,v in d1.items() if cond(v)]:
    del d1[k]
```

In case the list `[k for k,v in d1.items() if cond(v)]` would be too large, one might process the dictionary "in turns", i.e., to assemble the keys until their count does not exceed a threshold, prune the dictionary, and repeat until there are no more keys satisfying the condition:

```
from itertools import islice

def prune(d, cond, chunk_size = 1000):
    change = True
    while change:
        change = False

        keys = list(islice((k for k,v in d.items() if cond(v)), chunk_size))
        for k in keys:
            change = True
            del d[k]
```